# Python regression machine learning

Tags: python, selenium, machine-learning, regression

The full scenario:
On website addmefast.com on the top-right of the screen there is a number and the number is increasing over time.
My python program should guess the next number after X hours

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib




X=[]
y=[]

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bitfinex.com/')

elem_xpath = '//*[@id="homepage_wrapper"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]'

for i in range(1,20):
    time.sleep(0)
    try:
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, elem_xpath))) 
        X.append(float(elem.text))
        y.append(time.time())
    finally:
        driver.quit

### How to ask the program to predict bitcoin price at 8am ?


svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e4, gamma=0.1)
y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(X, y).predict(X)

print (y)
print (X)
print (y_rbf)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code and why it's not working?
Or do you have any solution for it?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lev\Desktop\ML\ML.py", line 26, in <module>
    X.append(float(elem.text))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,739.3'
```

If I remove the float() conversion I still get 'not convert' error

Comment: I would recommend splitting those lines for fit and predict just for the sake of readability. 

In addition, I see you are fitting on X and you use it for your predict the very same data, you should split train and test data.

What is the actual value of your y_rbf  and can you verify X is filled correctly ?

Comment: Yes, both X and y filled correctly.

Comment: what is the output of your print(y_rbf) ?

Comment: random numbers.

Comment: maybe you should increase your training set size

Comment: Have you already tried converting elem.text to a number? it is the text of the counter, right? Btw. don't you like to predict the number that the counter has on a specific time? if so, you should swap X and y. Then I guess 20 samples might not be sufficient even though there is only one input variable. And also `kernel='rbf'` appears suspicious to me. Does it really make sense to apply a kerne, if you only have one feature? Especially isn't what you try to predict very linear? so if you haven't tried already, try if you can improve your results by `kernel='linear'`.